# Is it legal to keep or make a digital copy of a physical book I bought?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, sweden

If we assume the book is copyrighted or a specific book that is not free of charge, it is commercial, can I make or download a digital copy of a book that I bought? I didn't buy the copyright and we can assume that it is copyrighted.

My geographic location is Sweden. The material in the book is not distributed to anybody else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no general right to download a copy of a book. You may acquire such a right from the rights-holder when you buy a physical book, but otherwise that would be illegal copyright infringement. Any online copy that you find in the wild is probably illegal, if the book is not free. (However, some books are freely downloadable *but* there is a charge for a printed copy: I assumt hat is not the case. You may *make* one copy for yourself. Under [Swedish copyright law](http://www.wipo.int/wipolex/en/text.jsp?file_id=129586), article 12:

> Anyone is entitled to make, for private purposes, single copies of
>   works which have been made public. Such copies may not be used for
>   other purposes.

Note that the law permit making a *single* copy, and does not mean you can make a Xerox copy then scan it, and later OCR the scan (that is making 3 copies).

Comment: What if I destroy the original copy?

Comment: That doesn't matter. Copyright law is about permission to copy, not the maximum number of copies that you can have.